# SSRS - Pick 1 word from a paragraph

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to pick the word "aaaaa.com" to a new column from the text "   Next to each other with 703125       ABC:  QWER => null - aaaaa.com . [VBN Res ID = 745075267#1(1/2)] Room 1 Comment: No meal is included in this room rate.  " which comes in a 1 column in SSRS.

Comment: What have you already tried? What went wrong? Where is your clear description of current and desired behaviour/output? This question needs some work to be of any use to anyway, please take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to output it as 2 columns in the dataset... but if you can't then the second option would be to use VB code.

Right click on the space behind your code and click 'Report Properties'.

Then in the Code section paste this:

```
Function SplitText(text As String, column As Int16) As String

        If (column = 1) Then
            Return text.Substring(0, text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf(".com") + 4).LastIndexOf(" "))
        Else
            Return text.Substring(text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf(".com") + 4).LastIndexOf(" ") + 1)
        End If
End Function
```

Then in your report use this expression for the first column:

```
=Code.SplitText(Fields!text.Value,1)
```

and this for the second

```
=Code.SplitText(Fields!text.Value,2)
```

and you have your result!

[image]

EDIT
Or if you just want the email address on it's own use this code:

```
 Function GetEmail(text As String) As String

        Dim Result As String
        Result = text.Substring(text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf(".co") + 3).LastIndexOf(" ") + 1)
        Result = Result.Substring(0, Result.IndexOf(" "))

        Return Result

    End Function
```